# iOS Swift ARKit Visualise Raw Feature Points from the ARWorldMap RawFeaturePoints

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, arworldmap

An `ARWorldMap` has `rawFeaturePoints`, which is a pointcloud of type `ARPointCloud`

Does anyone know how to go about visualising this pointcloud much like in the following video;

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Pb4uv4FSWKI

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly said, this could be achieved using `rawFeaturePoints` instance property, what represents notable features detected in the camera image.

```
var rawFeaturePoints: ARPointCloud? { get }
```

OR

```
sceneView.session.currentFrame?.rawFeaturePoints
```

> Here's an extract of [CODE](https://github.com/BlackMirrorz/ARPointCloud/blob/master/ARPoints/ARPoints/ViewController.swift#L5) written by **Josh Robbins** on a GitHub.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    guard let currentFrame = self.augmentedRealitySession.currentFrame,
    let featurePointsArray = currentFrame.rawFeaturePoints?.points else { return } 
    visualizeFeaturePointsIn(featurePointsArray)   
}

func visualizeFeaturePointsIn(_ featurePointsArray: [vector_float3]) {     
    self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (featurePoint, _) in           
        featurePoint.geometry = nil
        featurePoint.removeFromParentNode()
    }    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.rawFeaturesLabel.text = self.Feature_Label_Prefix + String(featurePointsArray.count)
    }  
    featurePointsArray.forEach { (pointLocation) in
        let clone = sphereNode.clone()
        clone.position = SCNVector3(pointLocation.x, pointLocation.y, pointLocation.z)
        self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(clone)
    }
}
```